# Full width without using "100%" property

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm using Angular Typeahead with a custom search-template, and for some reason the custom template won't respond when I set it's width to "100%".

I've also tried using jQuery to change the height, but it won't respond to this either, which leaves me with the last choice of creating media queries for every width I need.

I'm using SASS, and my question is: Is there a way of making the width of a div 100% without using the "100%" property?

My code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
<a class = "searchTemplate">
    <span ng-bind-html="match.model.name | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span><br>
    <span ng-bind-html="match.model.ticker | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
</a>
</script>
```

Working SASS/CSS:

```
.searchTemplate {
  @media screen and (min-width: $break5) {
    width: 500px;
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: $break4) and (max-width: $break5) {
    width: 500px;
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: $break3) and (max-width: $break4) {
    width: 400px;
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: $break2) and (max-width: $break3) {
    width: 300px;
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: $break1) and (max-width: $break2) {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

Not working SASS/CSS:

```
.searchTemplate {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: `width` property doesn't work with inline element like `<a>`, if you want it to take full width of the container use `display:block` for so.

Comment: @Pangloss The inline code was not supposed to be there and has now been removed, I added display: block to my external code and it did not work.

Comment: Not an expert on SASS, but as far as I can see, it might be using wrong syntax. `.searchTemplate` should be inside `@media ...`

Comment: @Pangloss It's correct and that is the working part of the code.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be like this? `@media screen and (min-width: $break5) {
  .searchTemplate {
      width: 500px;
  }
}`

Comment: @Pangloss No it should not. And as I said, that is the working part of the code, so you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

try this css:

```
left:0;
right:0;
```